# Bigquery readsessioncreate permission

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having trouble running this portion of the code to extract data from Bigquery.

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'cryptocurrency-research-416203-e7d96747012d.json'
project_id = 'cryptocurrency-research-416203'

client = BigQueryReadClient()

table = "projects/{}/datasets/{}/tables/{}".format(
    "bigquery-public-data", "crypto_bitcoin", "transactions"
)

row_restriction = """
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM block_timestamp) = 2009
"""

dfs = []

batch_size = 10000

**parent = "projects/{}".format(project_id)
session = client.create_read_session(
    parent=parent,
    read_session=types.ReadSession(
        table=table,
        data_format=types.DataFormat.AVRO,
        read_options=types.ReadSession.TableReadOptions(row_restriction=row_restriction)
    ),
    # It's possible to have more than one stream
    max_stream_count= 1,
)**
```

PermissionDenied: 403 request failed: the user does not have 'bigquery.readsessions.create' permission for 'projects/cryptocurrency-research-416203'

However, I think I have set the relevant permissions in the user account.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ydxE.png)

Can someone advise me on what to do? thank you.

I followed what chatgpt suggested.

Go to the Google Cloud Console IAM & Admin page.

Locate the user or service account associated with the provided credentials.

Click on the user or service account to view its details.

Click on the "Edit" button (pencil icon) to edit the permissions of the user or service account.

Add the role roles/bigquery.user or roles/bigquery.readSessionUser to the user or service account. These roles include the necessary permission (bigquery.readsessions.create) to create read sessions.

Save the changes.

Comment: you are using service account credential in code, however the permission you are showing is for your user.